# Не редиректит на 404 страницу

Tags: nginx, сервер

Не могу добиться, чтобы при переходе на несуществующую страницу перекидывало на мою кастомную 404 страницу. В блок `server` добавил такие команды:

```
set $errordocs /home/mrnr/www/error-pages;

error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
   root $errordocs;
}
```

При этом сама страница 404 по ссылке `/404.html` открывается

Comment: А у вас обработка точно не уходит в какой-нибудь php или django?

Comment: @andreymal кстати наверное вы правы, ведь 404 должно вернуть приложение, а nginx об этом не знает заранее. Хм, спасибо, вы мне помогли)